# Path Issues for "Cypress Run"

Tags: npm, cypress

I'm making good progress with Cypress but come a bit unstuck when trying to call a single Spec.

The line in `package.json` look like:

```
  "cypress:runST": "cypress run --spec'/cypress/integration/02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js'",
```

I start this with `npm run cypress:runST`...errors!

Even if I try running this as:

```
`npm run cypress run --spec '/cypress/integration/02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js'
```

I still get errors:

```
Can't run because no spec files were found.

We searched for any files matching this glob pattern:

'\cypress\integration\02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js'
```

and from NPM Logs:

```
10 silly lifecycle cypress_research@1.0.0~cypress:runST: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
10 silly lifecycle   'cypress run --spec \'/cypress/integration/02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js\'' ]
11 silly lifecycle cypress_research@1.0.0~cypress:runST: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle cypress_research@1.0.0~cypress:runST: Failed to exec cypress:runST script
```

I have a feeling it's the syntax in the command but then again if that was the case it would run 'bare'..but I get the same error. No idea where the '\' afer spec and after .js come from.

Any ideas please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming package.json is at the same level as the cypress folder, this should work

```
"cypress:runST": "cypress run --spec cypress/integration/02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js",
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked! it was the ' around the path causing issues...although these are stated as required on the Cypress site!

Answer (score 0):

From windows command prompt, `cd` to the cypress folder. Then please try running the command like below;

```
cypress run --spec cypress/integration/02_DBM_H1_ST_spec.js
```

The screenshot below, refer to an example of my test-spec.js run from the command prompt

[image]